# How to show/hide different table content based on map area click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I am trying to display a table with different content, based on the area that you click.

For example if I click on A (map area) I want to see only the information about A. And if I click on B (map area) I want see only information about B.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<map class="list-group" name="map">
  <area id="section-1" class="list-group-item" shape="rect" coords="198,368,142,337" href="#section-1" />
</map>

<img alt="Picture1" src="http://via.placeholder.com/680x466/444444/DDDDDD?text=Placeholder" width="680" height="466" usemap="map" data-cms="{'contentId':95875}" />

<table class="hide section-1" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <strong>Name&nbsp;</strong>
      </th>
      <th>
        <strong>&nbsp;Surname</strong>
      </th>
      <th>
        <strong>Addressf&nbsp;</strong>
      </th>
      <th>
        <strong>Postecode</strong>&nbsp;
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test&nbsp;</td>
      <td>test&nbsp;</td>
      <td>test&nbsp;</td>
      <td>test&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('.list-group a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.hide').hide();
    $('.' + this.id).show();
  });
});
```

Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/or17ny60/

Comment: Can you please make a jsfiddle with you problem? That would make things much easier.

Comment: @KrzysztofJaniszewski i have added the fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope that this is what you wanted

```js
$(function() {
  $('.list-group area').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.hide').hide();
    $('.' + this.id).show();
  });
});
```

```css
.list-group {
  min-height: 300px;
  min-width: 300px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.list-group area {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.list-group #section-1 {
  left: 0;
  background: #0F0;
}

.list-group #section-2 {
  left: 50%;
  background: #00F;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<map class="list-group" name="map">
  <area id="section-1" class="list-group-item" shape="rect" coords="198,368,142,337" href="#section-1" />
  <area id="section-2" class="list-group-item" shape="rect" coords="198,368,142,337" href="#section-2" />
</map>

<!-- <img alt="Picture1" src="http://via.placeholder.com/680x466/444444/DDDDDD?text=Placeholder" width="680" height="466" usemap="map" data-cms="{'contentId':95875}" /> -->

<table style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <strong>Name&nbsp;</strong>
      </th>
      <th>
        <strong>Surname&nbsp;</strong>
      </th>
      <th>
        <strong>Addressf&nbsp;</strong>
      </th>
      <th>
        <strong>Postecode&nbsp;</strong>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hide section-1">
      <td>test a</td>
      <td>test a</td>
      <td>test a</td>
      <td>test a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hide section-2">
      <td>test b</td>
      <td>test b</td>
      <td>test b</td>
      <td>test b</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: how do I hide the initial state of the table? i want to view it only when clicking. so the initial state should be hiddent at first. and then once clicked to show?

Comment: @unknownartist01 Just add `style="display: none;"` or add it in css

Comment: i have added it like this  <table style=" display: none; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">   but it's not showing the table on click now

Comment: @unknownartist01 Yes because my code does not hide and show table, but row. It hides / shows elemnts with `class="hide"` pay more attention to the code.

Comment: ok I get that but i want to show and hide the table not the row. Can you assist me with that?

Comment: @unknownartist01 Sure just add `class="hide"` to your table and proper class like `section-1` etc.

Comment: using the hide or even hide section to the table just hides the tables on click, and therefore not showing it. this is what i have added https://jsfiddle.net/hoq0djwc/500/ could you update the fiddle? because i am getting confused

Comment: @unknownartist01 I honestly have no idea why you did not want my solution, but sure here you go: [a solution without any sense](https://jsfiddle.net/hoq0djwc/501/), and here is: [a solution that makes more sense](https://jsfiddle.net/hoq0djwc/502/)

Comment: @unknownartist01 I know you didn't. I just don't see a reason to do it, and that's all. Have a good day too :)